# Post articles on facebook group via php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I have been looking on google for a while now but I can't find a proper solution...

What I would like to do is have a script on PHP that runs every hour and checks on my website for new posts from the registered users and then post each one of them to a **facebook goup** where I am the admin.

I have tried to look the facebook developers documentation without success.. it doesn't seem that I can just post my username and password to a facebook api or have a facebook developer app that manages my group..

did anyone do this before ? I would need to have an example of code in order to edit it to fit my requirements..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can NOT post using your username/password, you can ONLY post by authorizing an App with `publish_actions` and `user_managed_groups`. User an Extended User Token, it is valid for 60 days. After that, you have to refresh it manually.

There is example code and more information in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed#publish

Information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/